# Get separated RHS and LHS for a fixed variable for a given equation

Tags: python, equation, solver

For example, I have an equation `2x+3y-5t+1 = 3t-5(3x-5y)-2ty` and I want that `x` remains on the LHS and the rest of the variables `y and t` comes to the RHS. How can it be done in python?

Comment: can you post the code that you have tried for your problem

Comment: please post your code in question and not in the comment

Comment: @Prathamesh Jadhav I have put 4 spaces before the equation but it is still like this!

Comment: import sympy as sp
    from sympy import solve,Eq
    sp.init_printing()

    I1,X2_dot,K12,X1,X3,M12,X2,X4,X3_dot = sp.symbols('I₁ Ẋ₂ K₁₂ X₁ X₃ μ₁₂ X₂ X₄ Ẋ₃')
    I2,X4_dot,X3_d_dot = sp.symbols('I₂ Ẋ₄ 3Ẋ ')
    eq_1 = Eq((K12*X1)/M12-(K12*X3)/M12+X2-(I1*K12)/M12,X3_dot)

-> This is my equation and I want that K12 comes to the RHS and the rest all the variables comes to the LHS of the equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but you can solve this query using `sympy` Library.

The Python code for `2x+3y-5t+1 = 3t-5(3x-5y)-2ty` equation was stated below:-

```
# Import all-important Libraries
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

# Taken 'x', 'y', 't' variable for Our Equation from 'sympy.symbol'
x, y, t = symbols('x y t')

# Define Our Equation Using 'sympy.Eq' Module
# Format for Equation is:- equation = Eq(LHS, RHS)
equation = Eq(2*x + 3*y - 5*t + 1, 3*t - 5*(3*x - 5*y) - 2*t*y)

# Solve Equation Using 'sympy.solve' module
# Format for finding value of variable 'x' on LHS is:- solution = solve(equation, variable_you_want_to_find)
solution = solve(equation, x)

print(f'The Solution is:-\n', x, '=', solution)
```

```
# Output of Above Code:-
The Solution is:-
x = [-2*t*y/17 + 8*t/17 + 22*y/17 - 1/17]
```

If we write this equation on paper then It will be look like:-

[image: Markdown of Solved Equation]

As we can see we have achived our desired `output` of Solving both equation in such a way that `x` variable is on `L.H.S.` and other variable `y` and `t` on `R.H.S.`.

Hope this solution helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jay Patel. This is exactly what I wanted.